# Allow root to run games?

Tags: pi-2, root

So, I wanted my pi to run a game server on boot, but since root cannot run games, I can't run the game server on boot.If somebody could tell me how to do this, it would make my life easier.

When I try to run the command `darkplaces-server -basedir /place/to/gamefiles/ +"$(cat /place/to/precommands)"`, I get a not found error.

The game server I'm running is `darkplaces-server`, and does not require sound or graphical output. Keep in mind that I am also not using the X server.

Comment: I find it hard to conceive that root "cannot" do a thing. (Not saying that root "should" not do certain things). Could you please describe how you start the server (e.g. init scripts or cron)?

Comment: @Ghanima I start the server in a script. The command I'm using in a seperate script is: `darkplaces-server -basedir /place/to/gamefiles/ +"$(cat /place/to/precommands)"`

Comment: Try using the full path to the server and any other URL's in your script and make sure all the directories exist, to  make debugging easier have your script print the full command and cwd  then copy it to the command line and try running it,

Comment: There are some programs that do detect that they are being run as root - and for your own safety decline to start or just moan at you about it.  Usually there is a good reason not to do so and mechanisms are provided to gain any necessary privilege elevation when super-user powers ARE required.  FWIIW `darkplaces-server` is a rewritten **Quake** server - obviously the RPi is acting as a server for other devices and not participating as a player...

Comment: @SlySven Yes, I want my Pi to act as a server, and I think it's odd that I can't just let it start up at boot. I can make my Pi run the server when user pi logs in, but when I want to SSH into my pi to moderate the server, it just starts another server.

Comment: @Ghanima An application can refuse to run as root.  This doesn't mean a user with root priveleges can't run the application, just that they must do it `su` a less privileged user.

Comment: exactly what is the command you use to launch the server?

Comment: @Jasen It's already in the comments. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: The question is not specific to the Raspberry Pi, has been answered in the comments, and is asking the site to encourage foolishness.

Comment: @joan Yes, I should have asked this on Unix and Linux, sorry about that. I was just using my Pi, so I put the question here.

Comment: You should cut n' paste it yourself, because 1) It requires some editing to make the context clear (use the "raspbian" tag, U&L has one, but not a "pi2", which is irrelevant); 2) The timestamp does not change, meaning this would be 18 hours back in the queue and just get ignored.

Answer (score 2):

add this line to `/etc/crontab`;

`@reboot pi darkplaces-server -basedir /place/to/gamefiles/ +"$(cat /place/to/precommands)"`

replace `pi` with the apropriate username to run the server as

Comment: This did not work. I added the line above as you said. This also does not answer the question I asked, so I am down voting.

Comment: Did you ask a question?